# Convert base64 PDF to base64 image, without saving it to any file

Tags: php, base64, tcpdf

I do not know if it's a valid question to ask here but I'm tired of finding the solutions/libraries, so I had to ask for help from you guys.

Basically I'm generating a PDF using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and by using the parameter 'E' in the output method I get the the document as base64 mime (base64 String).

So as I'm building a API I don't want to save the PDF (or any file) on the server but just want to convert the output of base64 PDF to a base64 image (jpg) and throw the base64 output as json encoded.

So how do I convert the base64 PDF to base64 image (jpg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use imagemagick to do that.

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob($pdfBlob);
$imagick->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$imageBlob = $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

see http://php.net/manual/book.imagick.php

Comment: Turns out I never did my research fully, I already tried that but my base64 string was incorrect..